# how to save out result of curl open url https

Tags: php, curl, https

i try to save out of curl result to sql but it's not work

```
 $Curl_Session = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxx/feed');
 curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "access_token=$ad7kfarfish&message=$message");
 curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 $a8=curl_exec ($Curl_Session);
 curl_close ($Curl_Session);
```

i try every thing

i try

```
 $Curl_Session = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxx/feed');
 curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   $a8=curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "access_token=$ad7kfarfish&message=$message");
 curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_exec ($Curl_Session);
curl_close ($Curl_Session);
```

Comment: if you are saving to database, be sure to escape the data you want to save

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell cURL to return the transfer: `curl_setopt($Curl_Session,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);`

And then save the response with:
`$response = curl_exec($Curl_Session);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the response to be put in a variable, you need to do:

```
curl_setopt($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$a8 = curl_exec($Curl_Session);
```

Without this option, the response is passed through to the client (unless you use `CURLOPT_FILE`, which puts it in a file).